# Nested $.getJSON() not working in Cordova

Tags: jquery, rest

Please look at following code, i am unable to execute nested $.getJSON().  My url's are RESTful and when i run them seperatly in fiddler then they are working perfectly. I have also take care of CORS in the methods.

```js
var uri = "http://www.XXXXXX.XXX/WebService/api/controllername/Chk_mehtod/123";

$.getJSON(uri)
.done(function (data) {
   if (jQuery.isEmptyObject(data))
   {
      alert("data empty");
   }
   else
   {
      var Menu_uri = "http://www.XXXXXX.XXX/WebService/api/controllername/Menu_mehtod/465";
      
      alert("Till this alert, code is working");
                          
      $.getJSON(Menu_uri, function (menudata) {
          $.each(menudata, function (index, item) 
          {
             alert("Hyperlink:" + item.Hyperlink);
          });
      })
      .done(function () { alert("Inner Success"); })
      .fail(function () { alert("Inner Error"); });
   }
})
.fail(function () { alert("Outer Error"); });
```

I am developing my project in cordova...using visual studio 2015.

Any help will be appriciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Have you checked Chrome Developer Tools for any JavaScript or Network errors?

Comment: I have checked it in jsfiddler and it is working fine... but when i run it on android emulator then first getJson working perfectly but second failed.

Comment: Yes, I suspect it has to do with the whitelist plugin. Please open Chrome Dev Tools and select your emulator on the chrome://inspect page. You should then be able to see if there are any errors on the console. Please post those.

Comment: Thanks for reply, i have doubt that it has problem with the whitelist plugin... because when i run them seperatly, they are working... when i call them in nested then it is not working... i don't know more about Chrome Dev Tools... still i tried and got the following errors : 


GET file:///D:/Projects/LoginApp/LoginApp/www/cordova.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND


Refused to load the image 'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///ywAAAAAAQABAAACAUwAOw==' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src 'self' http://www.XXXXXX.XXX/"

Answer (score 0):

You should already have a meta tag in your HTML page, something similar to this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' 
    data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; 
    style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
```

Since there is no img-src value it defaults to 'self' but you're loading from data you fetched from an external source. So add an img-src value like this:

```
img-src 'self' data:;
```

Note the included colon.

You can read more about the content security policy at this handy website: http://content-security-policy.com/

Comment: Hi, 
now i have used following still error is there :
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' http://www.XXXXX.XXX/; img-src 'self' http://www.XXXX.XXX/" >

Error : GET file:///D:/Projects/LoginApp/LoginApp/www/cordova.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Refused to load the image 'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///ywAAAAAAQABAAACAUwAOw==' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src 'self' http://www.XXXX.XXX/"

Comment: I realize now that my initial answer would allow fetching an image from the external website. What you want is for it to allow the data: schema. I'll update the answer.

Comment: for as of now, I want to allow data: from external website...

Even if i remove "else" part from my script then too these two errors are there.... but my question is different... nested $.getJson not working... if i run the above two URL in different button click event then they will run perfectly... 

thank you for quick response....

Comment: The only error message you quoted, was the one about the content security violation. Are you seeing any other messages?

Comment: NO.... but i know i am missing something from cordova side only.... because when i run above script in jsfiddler ... result is proper...

I don't know how to get rid of this... thank you for your support...

Comment: I understand you only have the problem under Cordova, but if the $.getJSON fails, there should be a message. I keep harping on about Chrome Dev Tools, because it is brilliant for debugging Cordova apps. If you're using either cordova run or cordova emulate, you should see the session listed on the chrome://inspect page. Please open Dev Tools from there and look for (1) console errors when running the AJAX call, or (2) the status code returned on the network page for the AJAX call. If your network request has a status other than 200, please post both the complete request and response.

Comment: Hi Cobus, Now i don't found any error in Chrome Dev Tools... But still problem is there... Please help how to get rid of this error... Thank you.

Comment: And on the network tab? You should see the web service call listed there (if it happens at all). What is the status code shown?

Answer (score 0):

Now i understand, why it was not working for me because $.getJSON() is asynchronous and i have redirect code in first request...

$.getJSON() is a shorthand notation for $.ajax() which can be configured to be synchronous.

I learned too many new things while solving this bug.

Thank you for response.